# Why is my UIButton target action not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout, uiimageview

I am using Google Maps API, and I have created a UIButton to be placed on top of the map view. Inside that UIButton, I have inserted a UIImageView. For some reason, after I add a target action to the UIButton, the selector method is not being called. Here is an example of what the elements look like when the app is built:

[image: Screenshot of app running on device]

Here is my selector method:

```
@objc func goToListView() {
    print("Go to list view!")
}
```

Here is my UIButton code:

```
func configureReturnToListViewItem() {
    view.addSubview(returnToListViewItem)
    returnToListViewItem.backgroundColor = .white
    returnToListViewItem.layer.cornerRadius = 25
    returnToListViewItem.clipsToBounds = true
    returnToListViewItem.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    returnToListViewItem.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    returnToListViewItem.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    returnToListViewItem.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    returnToListViewItem.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 25).isActive = true
    returnToListViewItem.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
    returnToListViewItem.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToListView), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

And here is the code for the image inside the UIButton, just in case:

```
func configureReturnToListViewImage() {
    returnToListViewItem.addSubview(returnToListViewImage)
    let image = UIImage(named: "list")
    returnToListViewImage.image = image
    returnToListViewImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    returnToListViewImage.clipsToBounds = true
    returnToListViewImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    returnToListViewImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    returnToListViewImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    returnToListViewImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    returnToListViewImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: returnToListViewItem.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    returnToListViewImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: returnToListViewItem.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

I have tried tap gestures, as well as setting **isUserInteractionEnabled** to **true** for all elements within the view controller. I would love some guidance!

**Edit: My problem was due to an invisible navigation bar, caused by earlier configuration. In most cases, the other answer would be correct - so please use those answers as well if they apply to your situation.**

Answer (score 1):

Seems `returnToListViewImage` is covering up the `returnToListViewItem`. Try without the `returnToListViewImage` to see if it's getting the target triggered. If yes you can add a tap gesture on `returnToListViewImage` and set the target as `goToListView` don't forget to set the `isUserIteractionEnabled` is `true` for `returnToListViewImage` and it would work the same.

Better approach: You could directly set the image to the UIButton type `returnToListViewItem`, like this and this would require only one line instead of the whole function you've given.

```
returnToListViewItem.setImage(UIImage(named: "list"), for: .normal)
```

Comment: I tried it with removing the UIImageView, and it still didn't work with just the UIButton! Thanks for that tip on setting the image, though.

Comment: In that case, the issue doesn't seem to be occurring from the code snippet that you've posted. You might want to add more context for others to figure out what's wrong. Try adding the same button elsewhere and see if it works fine, see what you're doing different here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question by using the **view debugger** after running my application. In my specific case, my invisible navigation bar was covering the buttons, which prevented any interaction with anything underneath the navigation bar. All I had to do was add this line of code to my **viewDidLoad()** function:

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

The view debugger is a lifesaver!

Comment: I suspect you used the view debugger, not the memory graph